# Cómo puedo visualizar código HTML en una etiqueta <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo almacenado en el campo de una tabla en la base de datos; una cadena que tiene contenido "html" el cual quiero visualizar en un modal. He investigado y encontré la posibilidad de representar contenido html utilizando la etiqueta "< i frame >"; sin embargo; no encuentro un ejemplo de cómo asignar el contenido html a la etiqueta .

Alguien tiene algún ejemplo utilizando la etiqueta " < iframe > " o de cualquier otra forma, para poder visualizar el contenido html en un modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que tienes el valor de la cadena HTML en una variable, supongamos:

```js
const pintar = () => {
  //El codigo HTML que viene de la base de datos.
  let cadenaHTML = "<h2>la cadena</h2>"
  
  //Vanilla JS
  document.getElementById("id_del_elemento").innerHTML = cadenaHTML

  //Jquery
  $('#id_del_elemento2').html(cadenaHTML)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <h1>Toca el boton para modificar el contenido de los Div</h1>
  
  <button onclick = "pintar()"> pintar </button>
  
  <div id="id_del_elemento"></div>
  <div id="id_del_elemento2"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Facundo.¡¡¡

Comment: No hay de que @LuisHumbertoLlatasYovera, si la respuesta te pareció acertada, podes marcarla como correcta para que los demás puedan verla.